# SEO Inquiry; Domain Name selection

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, subdomain, country-codes

Can any one help me by clarifying the differences between DOMAIN NAME formats according to Google search engines and SEO perspective:

1. `example.com`
2. `ex-ample.com`
3. `example-eg.com`
4. `egypt.example.com`
5. `example.eg`
6. `example.com.eg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the `.com` (gTLD) and `.com` "subdomain" domains are treated similarly in the Google search engine. By default they don't target any country in particular. You can set a gTLD to target a specific country by using Google's [International Targeting report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209?hl=en) tool.

Do note that if you use a subdomain, Google [may treat your website as being "part of the same website" as the main domain](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-treats-subdomains-subdirectories-john-mueller-says/254687/).

In contrast, the `.eg` and `.com.eg` (ccTLD) domain extensions hint to Google that the website should target users in Egypt. With a ccTLD like `.eg`, ["it is already associated with a geographic region" and "you won't be able to specify a geographic location."](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209?hl=en) So, you'll be stuck targeting users in Egypt.

Comment: "stuck targeting users in Egypt", but also potentially ranking much better within Egypt than with a `.com`.